# xslt.Load(New XmlTextReader(New StringReader(xslt))) "xslt compile error"

Tags: vb.net

I have read the other posts and they are not resolving my problem.
The environment is VB 2008 (2.0 Framework)
The below code cause an `XSLT Compile error` on the `xslt.Load` line
Below that is the output from the error. I am passing the XSLT as a string, so not sure why I am getting the error I am.

```
Public Function xFrmTlogs(ByVal sXLST As String, ByVal sXML As String) As String
    Dim xslt As New XslCompiledTransform()
    Dim HTMLoutput As String
    Dim writer As New StringWriter()

    Try
        xslt.Load(New XmlTextReader(New StringReader(sXLST.ToString)))
    Catch ex As Exception
        xFrmTlogs = ex.ToString
    End Try

    Dim sourceReader As System.Xml.XmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(New System.IO.StringReader(sXML))

    Try
        xslt.Transform(sourceReader, Nothing, writer)
    Catch ex As Exception
        xFrmTlogs = ex.ToString
    End Try

    HTMLoutput = writer.ToString()
    writer.Close()
    xFrmTlogs = HTMLoutput
End Function
```

---

> System.Xml.Xsl.XslLoadException: XSLT compile error. An error occurred at (3,2). ---
>   System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'H:\Program 
>   Files\common\tr_period.xsl'.
>   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 
>   rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, 
>   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare 
>   share, Int32 bufferSize)
>   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials)
>   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type 
>   ofObjectToReturn)
>   at System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltLoader.CreateReader(Uri uri, XmlResolver xmlResolver)
>   at System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltLoader.LoadStylesheet(Uri uri, Boolean include)
>   at System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltLoader.LoadInclude()
>   at System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltLoader.LoadRealStylesheet()
>   at System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltLoader.LoadDocument()
>   at System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltLoader.LoadStylesheet(XmlReader reader, Boolean include)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltLoader.LoadStylesheet(XmlReader reader, Boolean include)
>   at System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltLoader.Load(Compiler compiler, Object stylesheet, XmlResolver 
>   xmlResolver)
>   at System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.Compiler.Compile(Object stylesheet, XmlResolver xmlResolver, 
>   QilExpression& qil)
>   at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.CompileXsltToQil(Object stylesheet, XsltSettings 
>   settings, XmlResolver stylesheetResolver)
>   at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.LoadInternal(Object stylesheet, XsltSettings 
>   settings, XmlResolver stylesheetResolver)
>   at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Load(XmlReader stylesheet)
>   at VfiSapphire.COMWrapper.xFrmTlogs(String sXLST, String sXML) in H:\Documents and 
>   Settings\xxx\My Documents\Visual Studio2008\ProgramName\ModuleName\PdkBo.vb:line 709

Comment: "Could not find a part of the path 'H:\Program Files\common\tr_period.xsl'" What happens if you type that path in Windows Explorer?

Comment: it is trying to reference a file on a web server ..\common\tr_period.xsl'

Comment: Then i think that "`.`" isn't what you think it should be. It's not the URL of the server, it's a file path.

Answer (score 0):

The XSLT script that is stored in `sXSLT` likely contains a `<xsl:include>` or an `<xsl:import>` element which tries to include/import another XSLT script file at `H:\Program Files\common\tr_period.xsl`.  Since that file doesn't exist, or is otherwise inaccessible, the transform fails.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue!
It is trying to access a .XLS file
The file is on a Web Server, How can I resolve this?

Comment: The tr_period.xsl file must actually an XSLT file, not an excel spreadsheet, or anything.  The include and import commands are used to include all the XSLT code from another file as if it was part of the same file, essentially.  So, if the file is not needed for the script to successfully run, you could just remove that line.  If not, you can fix the path to the correct location of the file.

Comment: I retrieve the XML and XLST from a Web Server. In the XLST there is a link, <xsl:include href="../common/tr_period.xsl"/>, I have moved that file into a target on my local hard drive. The parse is incomplete. I appreciate you helping me.